# Why both of my PHP regexp fail?

Tags: php, regex

```
$subject = "SPRINT-1.csv";
$pattern = '/^[a-zA-Z]\-[0-9]\.(csv)+$/';
if(preg_match($pattern, $subject)) {
 echo "Match";
} else {
 echo "NOPE";
}
```

or

```
$subject = "SPRINT-1.csv";
$pattern = '/^\w\-\.(csv)+$/';
if(preg_match($pattern, $subject)) {
 echo "Match";
} else {
 echo "NOPE";
}
```

Comment: Also, Expresso is a great tool for writing, understanding and TESTING regexes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A character class `[…]` does only describe one single character. So `[a-zA-Z]` describes one character out of `a`–`z`, `A`–`Z`. The same applies to `\w` (that’s also a character class).

You forgot to describe the quantity the characters from that character classes may appear, like:

- **`?`**: zero or one repetition
- **`*`**: zero or more repetitions
- **`+`**: one or more repetitions

Answer (score 1):

`'/^[a-zA-Z]\-[0-9]\.(csv)+$/';` you're missing the quantifier, it should be `[a-zA-Z]+` or `[a-zA-Z]*`.

Try out http://www.regexp.net/ to quickly optimize your regexp.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
$subject = "SPRINT-1.csv";
$pattern = '/^[a-zA-Z]*\-[0-9]\.csv?$/';
if(preg_match($pattern, $subject)) {
 echo "Match";
} else {
 echo "NOPE";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do either:

```
preg_match_all('/^[a-zA-Z]+\-[0-9]\.csv$/i', 'SPRINT-1.csv', $result);
```

or

```
preg_match_all('/^\w+\-\d\.csv+$/i', 'SPRINT-1.csv', $result);
```

In both case, you forgot the "+" before the letters that match "SPRINT", in the second case, you forgot the number to match "1".

And by the way, you don't need the "+" at the end of the pattern, nor the () around the csv.

But please, make an effort to write a complete question. Posting just code like that is not really handy to understand.

Finally, if you want to test regexp, use a [good tool](http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/).